# remove unnecessary buttons

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a question would like ask anyone expert in objective C and iPhone Dev.

I have a page used to add stuff to other page. Such as a have a page called artist. Open it will see artist history . Clicking it will lead to other pages carry the according contents. Inside each content has a button called add to favorite. Okey, now if the adding action made, this will add the entire artist to the favorite, and now if I go to favorite I see the icon for what I just added, click that I will be able to view the entire newly added content. But my problem is the add to favorite button is still there when I am already in the favorite page. I want the button to be disappeared when I go to that favorite page.
Please could anyone help me in this. My code is too long so i cant post it. So base on what i describe, just give me some hints or whatsoever. I really appriciate your help.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to elaborate on your implementation, how they're set up and how you navigate to all theses "pages". Are you using a UINavigationController? All we can do now is start stabbing in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use the standard ViewController approach:

In `viewWillLoad`, set the property of your addToFavoritesButton according to the status of the artist that will be shown:

```
addToFavoritesButton.hidden = artistShown.isFavorite;
```

In the method that adds an artist to the favorites, also do this:

```
- (void) addToFavorites
{
    ...
    artistShown.isFavorite = YES;
    addToFavoritesButton.hidden = artistShown.isFavorite;
    ...
}
```